# Live streaming web app developement uncertainty

Tags: wordpress, node.js, nginx, real-time

Please, be forgiving in matter of language mistakes. Thank you in advance for any time spent on this question.

Some time ago I came to idea about web/mobile app focused on delivering live video content mixed with users having interactions with each other in real time while they watch. I think there is no need for more specific description.

So, for my core functionality - streaming video, I decided to go along with Nginx server and plugin nginx-rtmp-module, because it seems to be most feature rich and well documented free solution.

But I have problem with deciding, which solution to pick for real time user interactions wrapped around my streaming server. After long research I left myself with 2 options.

Option 1 - Wordpress + nginx-push-stream-module

- I have some experience with Wordpress
- Lot of minor functionalities like user management, payment processing, admin panel, Facebook/Twitter integration are working out of the box and save alot of time
- I hate writing anything in PHP
- Wordpress is far far from being anything close to real time solution
- Higher resource usage on server

Option 2 - Nodejs + socket.io

- Really fast and real time oriented - core features of my app
- I like Javascript and it would be easier to focus only on one language
- Good solution in long term perspective
- I have to build everything from scratch
- Security? I have no idea how to secure my app

I want to build this app by myself and then, if it hits, hope I will get enough funds to make it better. I feel like Option 1 is best, but I'm scared I will soon find myself stuck with limits of this choice.

Please help me with your experience. Thank you for your time.